# Why a client create new instance on GAE just after a warmup request

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I use GAE for my small service. I have only 3 or 4 clients per day and never in the same time.
My service is written in Java with spring MVC, spring security and objectify.
So startup time can takes between 15 and 20s.

To avoid this startup latency for my client I activate billing and set min idle instance to 1 (and 1 for max).
But even with this configuration sometimes my client have to wait 15s for their first request.

As you can see in my log just after a warmup request (never used), the client launch a new instance (never used later to) :

Example 1:

```
2012-09-10 23:23:31.442 /myIndex.do 200 18997ms 15kb Mozilla
x.x.x.x - - [10/Sep/2012:14:23:31 -0700] "GET /myIndex.do HTTP/1.1" 200 15048 - "Mozilla" "www.mysite.fr" ms=18997 cpu_ms=10442 cpm_usd=0.001682 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117c2e937c04807734919256d8a5cee8

2012-09-10 23:05:05.260 /_ah/warmup 200 14225ms 0kb
0.1.0.3 - - [10/Sep/2012:14:05:05 -0700] "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 200 0 - - "3.360029581669528772.mywebsite.appspot.com" ms=14225 cpu_ms=8969 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117c10680b3f12b4c8f80f7b7191ce8bab
```

Example 2:

```
2012-08-31 18:51:16.096 /myIndex.do 200 14676ms 14kb Mozilla
x.x.x.x - - [31/Aug/2012:09:51:16 -0700] "GET /myIndex.do HTTP/1.1" 200 14954 "http://www.mysite.fr/myIndex.do" "Mozilla" "www.mysite.fr" ms=14676 cpu_ms=8514 cpm_usd=0.001671 loading_request=1 pending_ms=1022 instance=00c61b117cf69060fbcfbfe9dbd6ed735b869817

2012-08-31 18:39:43.895 /_ah/warmup 200 19812ms 0kb
0.1.0.3 - - [31/Aug/2012:09:39:43 -0700] "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 200 0 - - "3.360029581669528772.mysite.appspot.com" ms=19812 cpu_ms=10243 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117c1d4303f8698a615149d5a40dcac7
```

It worries me that I already have this type of problem with 4 clients :/

and also found a similar issue  http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7865

Can anyone confirm if these two problems are related?

Thx

Samuel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can properly answer your question, but I will do my best to put you on the right track.

Warmup requests are invoked by the application server before 'live' a request is sent to your application instance. It is a opportunity for you to invoke/initialize as much code as possible so it is loaded in memory. When a 'live' request hits you application it is then executed swiftly. Looking at your logs, the request to /myIndex.do takes 14s to execute. By any standard this is quite long.

This leads me suggest the following:

1. Try to figure out which libraries you are importing that cause the request to be so long. Once you have established that, make sure that you load/use them up in your warmup handler.
2. If it's not a library loading issue, that means you are doing a whole lot of processing in your request. I would suggest to delegate some of it, to asynchronous handlers (using AJAX).
3. Finally, you could a schedule task to invoke your /myindex.do on a regular basis (every minutes or so) to make sure it is "hot".

Comment: You are right about the idea of warmup requests but wrong about the situation described in the question. The log entries for the requests to index.do clearly state "loading_request=1", indicating that these requests were directed to new instances and did not use an existing ('warm') one. The requests take 15-19s because these new instances have to spin up first.